# WebRTC Trick Camera permission request

Tags: javascript, ios, safari, camera, webrtc

is there any way to programmatically trick the “camera permission request” in WebRTC maybe with JavaScript ? so permission is guaranteed without asking explicitly for permission and show camera stream right away ? I want to build a web app similar to Instagram and only ask the user once the web app is saved on homescreen for camera permission, not every time he opens the app.

cheers

Sebastian

Comment: No. And for a good reason.

Comment: sure I know the reason, but I want to build a web app so I want the user to confirm once and my web app saves the confirmation

Comment: that is done in browser settings. browser enforces the security settings/exceptions. you cannot do it from javascript, cause  otherwise bad guys would do it too.

Comment: That’s a point, so there is no way that the user confirms the permission once the web app is pinned to home screen and then never again ?

Comment: Browsers may allow user to allow resource usage w/o asking in one way or another via browser settings. like in chrome:
chrome://settings/content/camera?search=camera